# NodeJS+SOAP - Library is adding method name as tag

Tags: xml, node.js, soap

I'm trying to consume a SOAP service with Nodejs, I'm pretty new in Node, this is what i have:

```
var soap = require('soap');
var url = 'https://example.com?wsdl';

var params = 
{
    "ns1:requestEmisionOperativa": 
    {
        codigoFormatoImpresion: "1",
        ordenServicio: {}
    }
};


soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) 
{
    var soapHeader = {"ns1:requestHeader": 
                        {
                            idToken: "xxx",
                            "codigoUsuario": "xxx"
                        }};
client.addSoapHeader(soapHeader);

client.emitir(params, function(err, result) 
{
    console.log(result);
});
});
```

The XML generated is this:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://example.com/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:tns="http://example.com/" xmlns:ns1="http://example.com/" xmlns:ns2="http:/example.com/method">
   <soap:Header>
   <ns1:requestHeader>
      <idToken>xxx</idToken>
      <codigoUsuario>xxx</codigoUsuario>
      </ns1:requestHeader>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <emitir>
          <ns1:requestEmisionOperativa>
             <codigoFormatoImpresion>1</codigoFormatoImpresion>
             <ordenServicio>
             </ordenServicio>
          </ns1:requestEmisionOperativa>
      </emitir>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The root tag of the body is "emitir", which is the method name. If I remove (manually) those tags, the service works as it should, but I can't remove it programatically. In addition I'm not sure **what** I have to google (SO suggestion have no answers and "remove method name as root tag +soap +nodejs" didn't give any good result)

So, the question is: How can I remove method name as root tag?